# Could we use a multi-branch condition on a lambda python Pandas function?

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating a new Pandas column with the following code

```
temp['UFrio'] = temp['TempC'].map(lambda x: 0 if (x <0) math.sin((2*math.pi/28)*x) elif (x<25) else -1)
```

but it gives me an invalid syntax error.

Could you help me?

Thank you

Comment: `0 if x < 0 else math.sin((2*math.pi/28)*x) if x < 25 else -1`

Comment: @behzad.nouri: Please post an answer so it can be voted up.

Comment: @Bakuriu no! `1 if True else 2 if False else 3` gives `1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write it like this:

```
def thingy(x):
    if x < 0:
        return 0
    elif x < 25:
        return math.sin((2*math.pi/28)*x)
    else:
        return -1
temp['UFrio'] = temp['TempC'].map(thingy)
```

Likely you can come up with a better name than thingy. There is no need to put all that into a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

```
temp['UFrio'] = temp['TempC'].map(lambda x: 0 if (x <0)  else x)
temp['UFrio'] = temp['TempC'].map(lambda x: math.sin((2*math.pi/28)*x) if (x<25)  else -1)
```

i divide the if statement in to two because if u but elif will make an error so this my way to handle this problem i hope it help

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.